# Difference between `is()` and `is...()` functions

Tags: r

I have a simple question that might be helpful to the community here. Usually, in context of writing a function, I want to check if an object is of a certain class. I have two choices: I can use the generic `is(object, class)` or I can use a more specific function, like `is.list()`, `is.data.frame()`, `is.array()`, `is.numeric()`, `is.matrix()`, etc.

Consider if I want to test whether an object is a matrix. Are there any differences between `is(object, matrix)` and `is.matrix(object)`? Should one approach be used in some contexts, like checking if an argument is a certain class inside functions?

```
A <- matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 2)
is(A, "matrix")
is.matrix(A)

#Testing whether A is a data.frame. Both should be FALSE. 
is(A, "data.frame")
is.data.frame(A)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but I'd imagine an advantage to `is` is you can pass a character variable for the class.  This could cut down on code.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the base `is.` functions are primitives while `is` is not but I don't believe they should produce different results.  From what I can see, the difference is that not every class has an `is.` function written for it. If you use your own classes, `is()` can work with them:

```
x = 1:3
is(x, 'numeric')
class(x) = 'wouldntyouliketoknow'
is(x, 'numeric')
is(x, 'wouldntyouliketoknow')
```